# SoapUI maven plugin with Java 11

Tags: java, soapui, maven-plugin

Is there a version of this plugin **soapui-maven-plugin** working with Java 11? I am getting this error with the newest version 5.5.0 as well as with older:

```
Caused by: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <*> at index 95: C:\Users\username\.m2\repository\com\smartbear\utils\analytics\out-app-analytics-provider\lib\*.jar
```

I tried some exlusions which works on older Java versions, but errors still persist.

```
<exclusion>
  <groupId>com.smartbear.utils.analytics</groupId>
   <artifactId>*</artifactId>
</exclusion>
```

If not, can somebody suggest similiar plugin, where you can write SoapUI tests suite and execute them during build. Of course compatible with Java 11. Thanks